# jQuery Show/Hide Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm just trying to preform a very simple jQuery action.

I have two components: `#safety` and `#safety-tab a`, the `#safety` needs to be hidden on load. When the a link in the `#safety-tab` is clicked, it will `hide` itself and `slideUp` the `#safety`.

This sort of works, but the `#safety` box just flickers on click, doesn't stay shown:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#safety-tab a").click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
     $("#safety").removeClass("hide");  
   });
   });
```

While the markup is this:

```
     <div id="safety" class="hide group">
      ...
     </div><!--end #safety-->
    <div id="safety-tab">
      <a href="">...</a>
    </div><!--end #safety-tab-->
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` to your click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#safety-tab a").click(function( event ) {
     $(this).hide();
     $("#safety").removeClass("hide");  
     event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

This prevents the default behavior of the `<a>` element, which is reloading the page.

- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault

Using `event.preventDefault()` will preserve event bubbling which is sometimes needed.

Doing `return false;` will prevent the default behavior, but it will also halt the bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

try return false as you are clicking on a link;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#safety-tab a").click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
     $("#safety").removeClass("hide");  
     return false;
   });
   });
```